docker composeで作ったMySQLコンテナにアクセスできない
タイトルがおかしかったらすみません。
現在dockerでMySQLが入ったコンテナを作り、データベースなどを作っていきたいと考えているのですが、dockerでコンテナを作成後、mysqlコマンドでアクセスしようとするとエラーが出てしまい、先に進めないという状況です。
以下使用しているコードです。
docker-compose.yaml
version: "3.3"
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        container_name: db-for-go
        command:
            - --character-set-server=utf8mb4
            - --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
            - --sql-mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_USER: ${ROOTUSER}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${ROOTPASS}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${USERNAME}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${USERPASS}
            TZ: "Asia/Tokyo"
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - db-volume:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
    db-volume:


createTable.sql
create table if not exists articles (
  article_id integer unsigned auto_increment primary key,
  title varchar(100) not null,
  contents text not null,
  username varchar(100) not null,
  nice integer not null,
  created_at datetime
);

create table if not exists comments(
  comment_id integer unsigned auto_increment primary key,
  article_id integer unsigned not null,
  message text not null,
  created_at datetime,
  foreign key (article_id) references articles(article_id)
);

上記のyamlを元に、まず
docker compose up

でコンテナを作成した後、
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u docker sampledb -p < createTable.sql

でテーブルを作成しようとすると
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'docker'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

こういったエラーが出てしまい、テーブルを作成することができません。
パスワードがうまく設定されていないのかとdocker desktopでこのコンテナのenvironmentを確認しましたが、正常に適用されていました。

検索してもパスワードが設定されていなかったり、コンテナが競合していて設定がうまく反映されていなかったという原因であることが多く、私は今回初めてdockerを使ったのでそれらが競合が発生しているとは考えにくいです。
開発環境は
Macbook air (arm64)
MySQL 9.0.1
を使用しています。
足りない情報などあれば言ってください。
すみませんがよろしくお願いします。

試してみましたが再現しませんでした(正常にテーブルが作成されました)。 コマンドラインでパスワードを直接指定した場合 mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u docker sampledb -pdocker < createTable.sql はどういう結果になるでしょうか？
